# Running Octave-cli on Iterm/Zsh/Omgzsh in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, octave

It feels impossible to get it to run on any custom terminal. I know that octave-cli.app is there but it always opens in the standard terminal. Any ways to execute octave scripts like a compiler (or) run it interactively like an interpreter from Iterm?

Using Mac OSX 10.9+

Edit:
I know how to export path variables. But having searched the web can't find a way to do it. Is it even possible? I even tried it using homebrew to no avail.

Comment: Why feels this impossible? If you install GNU Octave via homebrew it should be easy as execute "octave" from the terminal

Comment: Just to clarify, typing octave in Iterm opens octave in another client. For reference, when you type python, it opens the interactive mode in the same Iterm window. Octave opens it in MacOSX Terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the content of octave-cli.app, it's a script. Mine goes like this

```
open -a Terminal.app /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/octave | logger 2>&1
```

It specify the terminal application used to open octave. This is the reason of your problem, as I think.

The solution is linking octave-cli in system path, better locates at "/usr/local/bin". like

```
ln -s /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/octave-cli /usr/local/bin/octave-cli
```

Finally, octave can be accessed via any terminal(like iTerm) or shell(bash, zsh) by just type "octave-cli" command, which will be searched in system path and found to executed directly.